# Зачем нужна метка _start в простой программе на NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

На просторах интернета нашел программу на NASM-е, которая выводит "Hello, world". Объясните, пожалуйста, зачем нужна метка `_start` в начале программы, если и без нее все будет работать?(если я не ошибаюсь)

```
 global    _start

          section   .text
_start:   mov       rax, 1                  ; system call for write
          mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
          mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
          mov       rdx, 13                 ; number of bytes
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do the write
          mov       rax, 60                 ; system call for exit
          xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
          syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exit

          section   .data
message:  db        "Hello, World", 10      ; note the newline at the end
```

Comment: Будет или не будет работать - почему бы просто не попробовать?

Comment: @insolor пробовал другую программу, которая делает тоже самое, только немного по другому написана, и там все работало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пусть имя файла `test.asm`, убираем глобальную метку `_start`:

```
section   .text
    mov       rax, 1                  ; system call for write
    mov       rdi, 1                  ; file handle 1 is stdout
    mov       rsi, message            ; address of string to output
    mov       rdx, 13                 ; number of bytes
    syscall                           ; invoke operating system to do the write
    mov       rax, 60                 ; system call for exit
    xor       rdi, rdi                ; exit code 0
    syscall                           ; invoke operating system to exit

section   .data
message:  db        "Hello, World", 10      ; note the newline at the end
```

Собираем:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 test.asm
$ ld -o test test.o
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0
$ ./test
Hello, World
```

Видим, что линкер искал метку `_start`, но не нашел, поэтому выбрал первый подходящий адрес, а именно начало секции с кодом `.text`. Под дизассемблером выглядит так:

```
.text:00000000004000B0 ; Segment type: Pure code
.text:00000000004000B0 ; Segment permissions: Read/Execute
.text:00000000004000B0 _text           segment para public 'CODE' use64
.text:00000000004000B0                 assume cs:_text
.text:00000000004000B0                 ;org 4000B0h
.text:00000000004000B0                 assume es:nothing, ss:nothing, ds:_data, fs:nothing, gs:nothing
.text:00000000004000B0
.text:00000000004000B0 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00000000004000B0
.text:00000000004000B0 ; Attributes: noreturn
.text:00000000004000B0
.text:00000000004000B0                 public start
.text:00000000004000B0 start           proc near
.text:00000000004000B0                 mov     eax, 1
.text:00000000004000B5                 mov     edi, 1
.text:00000000004000BA                 mov     rsi, offset message
.text:00000000004000C4                 mov     edx, 0Dh
.text:00000000004000C9                 syscall
.text:00000000004000CB                 mov     eax, 3Ch
.text:00000000004000D0                 xor     rdi, rdi
.text:00000000004000D3                 syscall
.text:00000000004000D3 start           endp
.text:00000000004000D3
.text:00000000004000D3 _text           ends
```

То есть в принципе программа соберется (и в данном случае даже будет работать), но точкой входа будет тот адрес, который выберет линкер.

Собственно, когда нужна метка `_start`:

1. Если программа изначально не должна запускаться с начала секции кода (например, сначала идут какие-то процедуры, а ниже - собственно точка входа)
2. Программа может собираться из нескольких объектных файлов, и перед началом кода основного модуля может оказаться какой-то другой код (опять же это могут быть какие-то нужные процедуры, но они не должны запускаться в первую очередь)

В любом случае лучше не надеяться, что линкер правильно угадает, чего от него хотят, а явно указывать точку входа.